# Titanium - change language programmatically

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I want to change the language of the app inside it. I want to allow the user to change the language from settings.

Is it possible?? because I can't find a setLocale() method or something similar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible using the build in tools. The build in tools are used by Android and iOS specifically to change the language based on the OS settings.

The way you can do this is by making it custom. Defining your own global function to get translations from (instead of the `L()` function). But this also requires you to put your translation files somewhere else.

Comment: Agreed! It also is not intended to change natively either

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. I am using this module from the marketplace:

iOS: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/144434#!overview

Android: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/144430#!overview

Answer (score 1):

The following line works although it is not documented. I think it will be documented soon and you will get a convenient way to change language on run time. Of course you will have define your own translation.

```
Ti.Locale.setLanguage("fr");
```

Comment: This works... however, the current L(strings) in view, must be manually changed, all other views, will automatically update.